# Почему код не проверяет условие (получение данных из AD)?

Tags: c#, ldap

Доброго времени суток!

Получаю данные по атрибутам пользователя из Active Directory.
Есть атрибут extensionAttribute4, в нем хранится дата рождения пользователя.Если это поле заполнено, никаких проблем с получением и вывод информации нет, НО если там пусто (Null) код при обработке запроса не читает условие. Что не так написал?

```
01: string displayName = directoryEntry.Properties["displayName"][0].ToString(); // Записываем ФИО
02: //LargeInteger extensionAttribute4 = directoryEntry.Properties["extensionAttribute4"].Value as Large LargeInteger;
03: string DateRod = directoryEntry.Properties["extensionAttribute4"][0].ToString(); // Записываем значение даты рождения
04:
05: if (DateRod == null)
06: { ad_fio.Text = displayName + "( дата рождения не указана )"; }
07: else { ad_fio.Text = displayName + " (" + DateRod + ")"; }
```

Ошибка при выполнении возникает на 3 строке, причем результат null он получает.
***Ошибка:** System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Индекс за пределами диапазона. Индекс должен быть положительным числом...'*

Ведь в самом атрибуте в АД стоит значение: <не задано> (Синтаксис = строка Unicod)

Comment: [раз](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3771223/c-sharp-testing-for-null), [два](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/83c3e38f-c8c0-4b4f-9293-5319e7ed04cb/c-ldap-null-user-attributes?forum=csharpgeneral)

Comment: Спасибо первый вариант то что надо!